# Maintain exact deep copy of remote repository

Tags: git

I am trying to maintain an exact copy (backup) of my remote repository. I run a cron job every day attempting to update from the remote. I would like to update the repository as is including all branches, tags, etc. I read about using the `--mirror` option in git, but it doesn't download the source. Additionally, I also need to add or remove any branches or tags that were added to the remote.

Considering my remote is named origin, I currently do the following things:

```
// clone
git clone --mirror https://my_site.com/path/to/repo.git repo/.git
// track all remotes
for remote in `git branch -r | grep -v /HEAD`; do git checkout --track $remote ; done
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

This method works alright, but it tries to checkout a remote everytime it runs and not when a new remote branch is found. Also, it does not delete the local branch if it was deleted from the remote. Same for tags I guess.

So...is there a better way to maintain a deep local copy/backup of my remote, dynamically handling every addition and deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mirror clone is a bare clone in which *all* ref names are copied on every `git fetch`.  Hence, to update a mirror clone, you need only run `git fetch` on the remote that the mirror is mirroring (typically origin): `git fetch origin`, or just `git fetch`, and when it is done, your mirror is updated.

> I read about using the --mirror option in git, but it doesn't download the source.

This statement makes no sense to me.  Git doesn't have "the source": Git has *commits*.  Each commit has a full and complete snapshot of every file.  If you have the commits, you have the files: not *the* source singular, but *every* file (in every commit).

My best guess is that you mean: a mirror clone has no work-tree.  That is true: that is what `--bare` *means*.  The reason not to have a work-tree is that if you are going to update *all* references—including all *branch names*—from some other Git repository, you had better not ever do any work in *this* repository at all, because this work will be destroyed every time you update this repository from the other repository.

To *use* a mirror clone, e.g., to build something, you should clone from it into a regular (non-mirror, non-bare) clone.  You can then add an additional remote to this regular clone.  If you want make new commits in this regular clone, and then to send these new commits to the repository from which you created the mirror clone, you will need that additional remote, so as to name the URL at which this other repository resides.

Hence a reasonably complete example might be:

```
cd place-where-mirrors-live
git clone --mirror $URL mirror.git
```

followed by:

```
cd place-to-work
git clone /path/to/place-where-mirrors-live/mirror.git working
cd working
git remote add upstream $URL
git checkout -b some-new-branch
... do work ...
git commit
git push upstream -u HEAD
```

followed by:

```
(cd /path/to/where-mirrors-live/mirror.git && git fetch --prune)
```

to update the mirror in `mirror.git` based on the update you made in `working` and then sent to the Git repository at `$URL` with your `git push`.

If you delete a branch in the Git at `$URL` using:

```
git push upstream --delete some-branch
```

the `git fetch --prune` step will delete the branch in the mirror.  You may wish to configure `fetch.prune` to `true` in the mirror, or in your personal (`--global`) Git configuration, so that *every* `git fetch` is a `git fetch --prune`.

You might, if you're really old-school about this, want to use `git remote update --prune` to update your mirror, but this is not supposed to do anything that `git fetch --prune` would not do.  (In the distant past, there were some Git bugs in this general area: not all prunes worked for all cases.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed write-up. And pardon my knowledge about git, I did mean the work tree when I said "source". The idea to clone the mirror into another local repository is a pretty neat idea. As I said, I just need the mirror to be an exact replica or the remote at all times and I guess --prune is just the switch I need.